# Magento 2 - How to override admin page.phtml?

Tags: magento-2.0.4

How do I override `\magento-root-dir\vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\admin\page.phtml`? I have successfully overridden the other files by placing the files under `\magento-root-dir\app\design\adminhtml\Company\Theme\Magento_Backend\templates`, but `page.phtml` just doesn't override!

I have even tried to change the core phtml file (just to debug stuffs obviously) and it doesn't show my modification. I have run `static-content:deploy` as well as `setup:upgrade` but still the same.

Why do I need it?
I want to change the structure of the admin theme which is a requirement for my current project. Particularly, I want to take the sidebar menu out and put a custom header menu instead.